# Align text inside table

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

I've currently got a list of 3 items. Each row has a small icon and text inside, all of it is pinned to the bottom of each row, however I need the text centered so it's in alignment with the middle of each icon. Here's my code I tried originally to use align with the span, but idk.

```
<ul id="server-list">
   <li><img src="images/home-icon.png" class="item" alt="Server Name" /> <span id="s-name">Server Name</span></li>
   <li><img src="images/screen-icon.png" class="item" alt="Game Mode" /> <span id="s-mode">Server Game Mode</span></li>
   <li><img src="images/map-icon.png" class="item" alt="Map Name" /> <span id="s-map">Server Map Name</span></li>
</ul>
```

Here is my css

```
.item {
    margin: 8px;
    height: auto;
    width: 13%;
}
#server-list span {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-top: -10px;
}
#server-list li {
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: url("images/icon-bg.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 420px auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    list-style: none;
    height: 85px;
}
```

I need to get from

> O____

to

> O----

Comment: did you tried line-height property?

Comment: I tried it, text didn't budge

Comment: can you create a demo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `display: inline-block;` and  `vertical-align: middle;` to both `image` and `span`

```
.item{
    margin:8px;
    height: auto;
    width: 13%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

#server-list span {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-top: -10px;
     vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;

}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b97zLos5/1/)**

Comment: 5Mins till I can accept the answer, thanks! worked a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.item{
    margin:8px;
    height: auto;
    width: 13%;
}

#server-list span {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-top: -10px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-right: 30em;
    width: 300em;
    

}

#server-list li {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table;
    background: url("images/icon-bg.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 420px auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    list-style:none;
  
   

}
```

Try this